# Invoke-DbaQuery Failure - Cannot open database ' ' requested by the login

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012, dbatools

I have this problem with my script.
I am using `dbatools`

```
$query= "select sid from sys.database_principals where type != 'R' "
$SQLInstance='localhost\NEWINSTANCE'

$databases=get-dbadatabase -SqlInstance $SQLInstance -ExcludeDatabase tempdb, master, model

foreach($db in $databases)
{

Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $SQLInstance -Query $query -Database $db 
}
```

So the problem is this

> Message error: [Invoke-DbaQuery] Failure | Cannot open database "[everydatabase in my instance]" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'my user'

Comment: SQL Logins have a default database setting. What's the chance that the login's default database has subsequently been dropped?

Comment: Check out Sql Server's error log, it contains [more details](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456).

Comment: according to error log: Login failed for user 'user'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '[database-name]'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: See the exact error code, it's the next row. Anyway, it looks like either database name is misspelled (are you running case sensitive instance?), the database is not available or the user doesn't have permission to connect into it.